# Is $B:=B_1(0)\backslash \{(0,t) : -1\leq t \leq 0\}$ closed or open?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

> Let $\mathbb{R}^2$ be given with $|\cdot |_\infty$. Is
>   $B:=B_1(0)\backslash \{(0,t) : -1\leq t \leq 0\}$ closed or open?

**My Ideas:**

I drew a picture first:
[image]

$B$ is the blue parts without the red line. I believe that $\{(0,t) : -1\leq t \leq 0\}$ is closed and that $B_1(0)$ is open. An open set without a closed set should be open. (correct me, if i'm wrong)

I am really stranded when it comes to proving it formally.

Comment: You are correct. This argument applies more generally; if $X$ is a topological space, $U$ is an open set, and $A\subset U$ is a closed set, then $U\setminus A$ is an open set.

Comment: You are correct that it is open, and your reasoning is sound. You could also prove it explicitly: take any point in your set and you should be able to find a “ball” around it which remains in the set (“ball” is in quotes because it is a ball in the pertinent norm, so it’s actually a square). It is not closed because it doesn’t contain all its limit points: consider the sequence $\{(1/n, -1/2)\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$ for example. It can also be noted that all the norm topologies on $\mathbb R^n$ are equivalent, so you could analyze the set in the standard topology and the same answers will hold.

Comment: I have to show that for all $x\in A$, there is a $\varepsilon >0$ such that $B_\varepsilon(x) \subset U$... Hmm, how would you choose $\varepsilon>0$?

Comment: Depending on your definitions, there may be nothing to prove. A closed set is, by definition, the complement of an open set. Thus, an open set minus a closed set is the same as the intersection of two open sets, and is therefore open.